# Connecting development board board to sensor

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, board, nordic

I am trying to connect a Nordic nRF52840DK board to the LSM6DSL sensor (accelerometer) on a STEVAL-MKI178V2 adapter board. The goal is to successfully connect the devices and test the sample [program](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/samples/sensor/lsm6dsl/README.html) from zephyr RTOS of outputting the data from the accelerometer.

The user guide to the nRF52840DK board can be found [here](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF52840_DK_User_Guide_v1.2.pdf), and the schematic on page 28 maybe helpful. The spec sheet for the adapter board and the sensor can be found [here](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/389/steval-mki178v2-1848661.pdf).

I know that I need to connect VDD and GND first, but there are also pins like SDO, SDA, SCL, CS, INT1, INT2 pins that I'm not sure what to do with. I was wondering if anyone could explain which pins are needed and why.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The names of the pins suggest that this sensor board uses an SPI or I2C serial interface to the processor. If your question really is "How do I use I2C on my processor" then I think your question is much too broad. You will need to do some learning before you dive into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the LSM6DSL datasheet for details.  The sensor has several options so the datasheet seems complicated at first.  Focus on the options/features that you're planning to use.  Refer back to the datasheet as you read this answer to confirm and hopefully clear things up.

First choose the communications method.  The LSM6DSL sensor supports either I2C or SPI.  SPI is preferred because it can be clocked at a greater rate (i.e. more bandwidth), which can allow you to read samples faster.  If you have a spare SPI port on your microcontroller and don't have a preference for I2C, then choose SPI.

Then connect the microcontroller communications port to the sensor.  For SPI connect:

- Microcontroller's SPI Clock (SCK) to Sensor's SCL
- Microcontroller's MOSI to Sensor's SDI (microcontroller output to sensor input)
- Microcontroller's MISO to Sensor's SDO (microcontroller input to sensor output)
- Microcontroller's SPI Chip Select (CS/NSS) to Sensor's CS

For I2C connect:

- Microcontroller's I2C Clock (SCL) to Sensor's SCL
- Microcontroller's I2C Data (SDA) to Sensor's SDA
- Sensor's CS pin to Vdd (to enable the sensor's I2C mode)

The INT pins are optional.  Read the sensor datasheet and decide whether you want to use the INT pins.  INT1 is an output from the sensor and will most likely be connected to an external interrupt (or a GPIO that functions as an external interrupt) on the microcontroller.  INT2 has more features and it could get connected to an external interrupt or a GPIO pin on the microcontroller depending on how you plan to use it.

For examples of how to connect the sensor, look at the schematics of the STMicro eval boards containing an LSM6DSL.